# Java app returns the curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8042)

Tags: java, rest, curl, terminal

I work with a Spring boot app and a few end-points returns an error

```
 $ curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/calculateReward?userId=1   |jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0parse error: Exceeds depth limit for parsing at line 1, column 6472
100 81714    0 81714    0     0  1641k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1662k
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 7978)
```

I also get the error like `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9`.

I think this is related to the pipe separator but I previously used it without an issue.

When I debug, I get something like this
`Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.user.reward.models.RewardList.toString()`

My model's classes are provided,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "countryName")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String countryName;


    /*
     * total steps is for the keepign the history of the user movement
     * */
    @Column(name = "totalSteps")
    @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
    private int totalSteps;

    /*
     * current steps is for providing the user reward. We will need to set
     * it to zero after processing the user payment
     * */
    @Column(name = "currentSteps")
    @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
    private int currentSteps;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RewardList> rewardLists = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(@NotNull @NotEmpty String name, @NotNull @NotEmpty String countryName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public User(@NotNull @NotEmpty String name, @NotNull @NotEmpty String countryName, @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive") int totalSteps) {
        this.name = name;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.totalSteps = totalSteps;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public int getTotalSteps() {
        return totalSteps;
    }

    public void setTotalSteps(int totalSteps) {
        this.totalSteps = totalSteps;
    }

    public int getCurrentSteps() {
        return currentSteps;
    }

    public void setCurrentSteps(int currentSteps) {
        this.currentSteps = currentSteps;
    }

    public List<RewardList> getRewardLists() {
        return rewardLists;
    }

    public void setRewardLists(RewardList rl) {
        this.rewardLists.add(rl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return getTotalSteps() == user.getTotalSteps() &&
                getCurrentSteps() == user.getCurrentSteps() &&
                getId().equals(user.getId()) &&
                getName().equals(user.getName()) &&
                getCountryName().equals(user.getCountryName()) &&
                getRewardLists().equals(user.getRewardLists());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getName(), getCountryName(), getTotalSteps(), getCurrentSteps(), getRewardLists());
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", countryName='" + countryName + '\'' +
                ", totalSteps=" + totalSteps +
                ", currentSteps=" + currentSteps +
                ", rewardLists=" + rewardLists +
                '}';
    }
}





@Entity
public class RewardList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "reward")
    @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
    private double reward;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public RewardList() {
    }

    public RewardList(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public RewardList(@Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive") double reward) {
        this.reward = reward;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getReward() {
        return reward;
    }

    public void setReward(double reward) {
        this.reward = reward;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof RewardList)) return false;
        RewardList list = (RewardList) o;
        return Double.compare(list.getReward(), getReward()) == 0 &&
                getId().equals(list.getId()) &&
                getUser().equals(list.getUser());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getReward(), getUser());
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RewardList{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", reward=" + reward +
                ", user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am in the OS X terminal, What's the solution for the issue?

Comment: you should guard in code against that. You can clean input with regex expression for example. But would be nice to see you code.

Comment: Have you consulted the JSON data `jq` complains about? Is it incredibly bloated and invalid as `jq` states? If so, can this be fixed in the Spring boot app?

Comment: I updated the question with a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency between `RewardList` and `User` entities when displaying them with `toString()`. User A will display reward B which will display user A which will display reward B... and on until you get `StackOverflowError` from recursive `toString()`.

You can resolve it by either:

1. not displaying `rewardLists` relationship data in the `User.toString()`
2. not displaying `user` relationship data in the `RewardList.toString()`

I'd go with option 1 as `User` is the owning entity for this relationship.

Comment: The error goes away but I still get in the terminal `parse error: Exceeds depth limit for parsing at line 1, column 6472 curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8026)`

Comment: And it does print `User{id=1, name='Robert', countryName='Germany', totalSteps=200, currentSteps=0}`